# border issue when export to pdf

Tags: php, laravel, tcpdf

**Versions:**

> PHP version: 7.0.8
>
> Laravel version: 5.6
>
> Package version: 2.1.0

**Description:**

Hi, We have tried to use Laravel-Excel export pdf file function by tcpdf,
but got the issue of the border was different.

Would you teach us how to [fix this issue](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/4566785/65020433-c2830e00-d95f-11e9-9995-bb3e5b973318.png)

Comment: wkhtmltopdf is much easier and actually lets you use css

Comment: How can we fix your issue if you don't share your code? We are not magicians..

Comment: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/687/how-to-configure-a-header-and-footer-in-dompdf refer this

Answer (score 0):

I am used tcpdf and also had try to use the dompdf but not work on php 7.1 or higher.

the following was my code:

public function exporttasklist(Request $request, Job $job)
    {

```
    $pathToFile = storage_path('app/xls/task.xlsx'); // find the xltx file

    Excel::load($pathToFile, function ($doc) use ($job) {

        $tasks = Task::where('job_id', $job->id)
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
            ->get();

        $Company = Company::where('id', $job->company_id)->first();


        $sheet = $doc->setActiveSheetIndex(0);  // access to sheet 1


        $sheet->setCellValue('C4', $job->JobNo);
        $sheet->setCellValue('C5', $job->JobName);
        $sheet->setCellValue('L4', $Company->CompanyName);
        $sheet->setCellValue('L5', $Company->CompanyChineseName);

        $sheet->getStyle('L5')->getFont()->setName('msungstdlight');
        $sheet->setCellValue('P4', $job->JobTranslationDirection);
        $sheet->setCellValue('P5', $job->JobTranslationTeam);
        $sheet->setCellValue('R5', $job->JobSales);


        $styleArray2 = array(
            'borders' => array(
                'top' => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,

                ),'bottom' => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE,

                ),'left' => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_NONE,

                ),'right' => array(
                    'style' => PHPExcel_Style_Border::BORDER_THIN,

                ),
            ),
        );
       $sheet->getStyle('A7')->applyFromArray($styleArray2)

        }

    })->export('pdf');
```